# Trusted Web Activity - Screen Orientation

Tags: android, trusted-web-activity

How do I set the default orientation to landscape when opening a url (TWA) from my application which is in portrait mode? (The TWA is launched from the second activity of the application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for setting orientation at launch is in development. You can check out the progress at: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/pull/122